# Set Dynamic Page Title from Widget Block in Magento 2

Tags: widget, magento2

I created a custom widget in Magento 2 and would like to dynamically change the page title in the Block's code. However, I can't seem to overwrite the page title that gets set in `Magento\Cms\Block\Page::_prepareLayout()`.

From inside my block I have the following function. As you can see I've tried a handful of ways to make the changes to see if I can get any result.

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set('TESTING');
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->append(' - TEST');
    $this->pageConfig->setMetadata('title', 'Meta Title Test');
    $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('mytestclass');

    $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
    if ($pageMainTitle) {
        $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle('Page Heading Title');
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

I ran the page load through xDebug and according to the debugger my `_prepareLayout` does get called **after** the default `_prepareLayout` that originally sets the title. And looking through the variables in the debugger the above code all appears to be successful. However, when the page actually renders none of the above is implemented. Not even the body tag added.

I don't see much out there in regards to trying to do this from a widget block. I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing here, or if I'm approaching this the wrong way. Maybe there's a better way to achieve what I want.

Yes, I cleared, flushed, and disabled all of the cache.

Using Magento version 2.1.2

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you find a solution?))

Comment: @Hobroker That was over a year ago so I can't remember for sure. But looking at the commit history it looks like I might have created a Plugin on `Magento\Cms\Model\Page` and set it in `afterGetTitle`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I know where to look now